# Show Item when Hover Over Parent

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table and I'd like the contents of one cell (`<td>`) hidden unless the mouse hovers anywhere over the parent row (`<tr>`).

It's pretty straight forward to show an element on hover, but I'm not sure how to show another element than the one being hovered over.

Can this be done with CSS alone, or do I need some sort of JavaScript? (I have jQuery and jQuery UI available.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
tr:hover > td {
    display:inline;
}
```

This is assuming whatever you're hiding is hidden with `display:none;`. Just use whichever property is appropriate for your situation.

**EDIT:** I changed it to `display:inline` because in the case of tables, you probably want the cells to remain next to each other rather than above and below.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/C5YCG/).

Comment: Thanks. However, that was causing a bunch of formatting issues. Seems better to place a `<div>` within the cell with class `command-panel`. But I can seem to be able to modify your code. I tried `tr:hover > div.command-panel { display:block; }` but that's not right.

Comment: @Pumou: I tried the example http://jsfiddle.net/YLHke/1/, but it is not working for me. what is wrong in this??

Comment: @SunilKumarBM: It is working, which is apparent by the fact that it shifts a little bit. The thing is that you're not selecting the hidden row in your `hover` selector.

Comment: @JonathanWood: Use `tr:hover > td div.command-panel {display:block;}`.

Comment: What is the necessary change I need to make??

Comment: @Sunil: Please state which browser you are using. Works for me in Chrome and IE9. Oh, I see the modified code does *not* work.

Comment: @SunilKumarBM: Since you're asking a very different question, it is better for you to ask a new question. You're free to link it here for me to answer.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is set up a div inside that `td`, set it's opacity to 0 and add a transition like this

```
.command-panel {
   opacity: 0;
   -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
   -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
   -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
   transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
}

tr:hover .command-panel {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

that way you'll have a nice but short enough animation

Comment: Hmmm... `-moz-transition` doesn't look very general across all browsers.

Comment: well it's only for firefox, as i mentioned in the comment, you need to add the rest for other browsers (this could be easily done with a mixin if you would be using something like SCSS and Compass). I modified the answer with what compass generates

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table style="border: 1px solid #ccc">
            <tr  onmouseover="document.getElementById('mytd').style.display='block'"
                 onmouseout="document.getElementById('mytd').style.display='none'"
                 >
                <td>
                    fgfgdgd1

                </td>
                 <td style="display:none" id="mytd">
                    fgfgdgd1

                </td>

            </tr>

        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. If I'm going to script it, I'll probably use jQuery. But my preference is to use CSS, if that's an option.